# Retrieving a specific value using an accessor method with an array return type

Tags: java, arrays, accessor

I have an accessor method which returns an array. Here's a bit of code to give you context...

```
   public void setCoordinate (double x, double y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }

   public double[] getCoordinate() {
      return new double[] {x, y};
   }
```

I want to use x and y later on, but I'm not sure how to call the getCoordinate method without retrieving both the x and y variables. I know how to call a method, but I'm not sure how to call specific value from the array using the accessor method.

Comment: Why don't you just define two different accessors? One for `x` and one for `y`.

Comment: `getCoordinate()[0]` gives you the `x` value since arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: @superEb, so if this were in a method that was calling locationA and locationB, would it be 'locationA.getCoordinate()[0];' ? I tried something similar to this and it didn't work.

Comment: If `locationA` is an instance of the class that defines the `getCoordinate` method in the OP, then yes. As others have mentioned though, it would probably be a better design to have separate accessor methods for `x` and `y` if you need to use one without the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store the array and use it later. Like so -

```
double[] coordinate = getCoordinate();
...
...
...
x=coordinate[0];
y=coordinate[1];
```

Comment: Which method would you suggest this go into? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Any one. The point is that you are storing the double array for use at any point. So some higher level function calls `getCoordinate()` and stores the answer for use at a later (or maybe even immediate) time.